cdata connect (OData) stored proc error "code": "consumSpRS"
Using CData Connect to expose Oracle STORED proc, I just get a java exception for which I cannot find any fixes for.
*[ODATA][2024-11-07T04:38:30.065Z][ERROR] rssbus.RSBException: [rsb:load_operation] The operation 'portGetProfile' could not be found.
Stack Trace: 
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.lni.d(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.ami.l(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.umi.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.gli.b(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.gli.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.ami.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.qki.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.qki.getFeed(Unknown Source)
    at rssbus.appops.Notify.a(Unknown Source)
    at rssbus.appops.Notify.exec(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.umi.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.umi.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.umi.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.ami.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.ami.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.qki.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.qki.call(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.nfi.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXcdata.connectX220X8262.nfi.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Has anyone seen something like this before?
